# Генерация XML документа php domDocument

Tags: php, xml

```
Всех приветствую 
Подскажите, хочу создать следующую структуру
```

```
   
    <data>
     <cars>
      <car>
       //
      </car>
     </cars>
    </data>
```

```
Вот мой код
```

```
            $dom = new domDocument("1.0", "utf-8"); // Создаём XML-документ версии 1.0 с кодировкой utf-8
            $data = $dom->createElement("data"); // Создаём корневой элемент
            $cars = $dom->createElement("cars");
            $dom->appendChild($data);
            $data->appendChild($cars);
    
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($auto); $i++) {
                $car = $dom->createElement("car");
                $unique_id = $dom->createElement("unique_id", $auto[$i]['unique_id']);
                $mark_id = $dom->createElement("mark_id", $auto[$i]['mark_id']);
                $car->appendChild($unique_id);
                $car->appendChild($mark_id);
                $data->appendChild($car);
            }
    
            $dom->formatOutput = true;
    
            echo $dom->saveXML();
```

```
На выходе получаю следующее

<data>
 </cars>
  <car>
   //
  </car>
</data>
```

Понимаю что проблема мелочная) Но к сожалению уже закипел((

Comment: ну сделай `$data->appendChild($cars);` после цикла

Comment: а car надо в cars добавлять а не в data

Answer (score 0):

Вместо этой строки в цикле:

```
$data->appendChild($car);
```

используйте эту строку:

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName("cars")->appendChild($car);
```